# InvalidOperationException: An invalid request URI was provided. The request URI must either be an absolute URI or BaseAddress must be set

Tags: c#

I'm trying to connect to Cognitive Services Face API by using Connected Services in Visual Studio in Asp.net Core by following tutorial

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/face/vs-face-connected-service

but in executing the REST API Call

```
var response = client.PostAsync(uri, content).Result;
```

i get this Error

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'An invalid request URI was provided.
The request URI must either be an absolute URI or BaseAddress must be set.
```

I have active subscription on azure and on cognitive services and API key is correct.

Comment: What's the value of `uri`?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto 
         string requestParameters = "returnFaceId=true&returnFaceLandmarks=false&returnFaceAttributes=age,gender,headPose,smile,facialHair,glasses,emotion,hair,makeup,occlusion,accessories,blur,exposure,noise";

 string uri = faceApiEndPoint + "/detect?" + requestParameters;

Comment: What's the runtime value, the end result, the value used when you actually perform the call

Comment: Copy the value of uri out of the debugger and paste it into a browser address bar--can you navigate to the uri? Most likely the problem with the uri will then be obvious.

Comment: @Polyfun   Ok i figure out what's the problem. I changed faceApiEndPoint = this.configuration["FaceAPI_ServiceEndPoint"]; to  faceApiEndPoint = "FaceAPI_ServiceEndPoint".